# Spark Streaming Windowing Function reduceByKeyAndWindow(

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am learning about spark streaming, and i came across the function `reduceByKeyAndWindow`. It seems to be passed two lambda functions in official documention

```
reduceByKeyAndWindow(lambda x, y: x + y, lambda x, y: x - y, 30, 10)
```

I am a bit confuse, as to why second function is passed. As far as i know one function to reduce value is enough. I wanted to know what is the significance of the second function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function is the actual *reduce* function. In this case you add the elements. The second is the *inverse* of the reduce function and it "undoes" what the reduce has computed, namely it performs a subtraction.

For example consider such window with overlapping values:

```
stream 2 3 5 8 1 ...

reduce = add
2 3 5 3 5 8 5 8 1 ...
|___| |___| |___| 
  10    16    14
```

Now in the example you could obtain `16` by adding `3+5+8` but since you already have `2+3+5` you "inverse reduce" by removing `2`, i.e. you perform the subtraction (remember: reduce is sum, inverse of reduce is subtraction).

```
10-2
```

and then add `8`. So, instead of computing `(3+5) + 8 = 16` you compute `(10-2) + 8 = 16`.

From the source code  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala

> 1. reduce the new values that entered the window (e.g., adding new counts)
> 2. "inverse reduce" the old values that left the window (e.g., subtracting old counts)

The advantage is that you avoid repeating the same computation. I assume that also caching values can bring some performance advantage.

Note that this can be done only for invertible functions (see also https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations).